# Android,how to disable confirm dialog when open wifi by code

Tags: android, wifi, confirm

When i open wifi by code like this:

```
WifiManager wifim = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifim.setWifiEnabled(true);
```

it woks.
but the android system self open a confirm dialog like this:

```
                      Warning
     The appliction WifiOpenTest is trying to trun on
     Your WLAN connection.Do you want to allow this?

        DISALLOW                   ALLOW
```

What I want to ask is can I open Wifi in source without show this dialog.
Thanks.

Comment: Its totally impossible. Because it gives that pop-up due some security constraints. So every time it'll definitely ask you for confirmation, without confirmation it won't start wifi/bluetooth directly.

Comment: Upvote my comment, if its helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following to your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: I've added.And I think it's about the phone strategy.Other mobile phone may not appear on this problem. I try the next.